# SQL Group by with string concat and CASE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to understand SQL Group By concept along with the Select statement having:

1. String concat operation
2. CASE statement

I understand the Select clause is evaluated after the Group by clause and that any non aggregated columns in the Select list also need to be present in the Group By list. I will try to explain my questsion with an example ORDERS table that has one record for each order:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME +' '+LASTNAME
,EMP_TITLE
,EMAILADDR
,INACTIVE
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(EMAILADDR,'')='' THEN 'ADMIN@MYCOMPANY.COM' ELSE EMAILADDR END AS ALTEMAIL
,CASE WHEN AGE>60 THEN 'SENIOR' ELSE 'EMP' END AS EMPTYPE
,COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_ORDERS
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME + ' '+ LASTNAME
,EMP_TITLE
,EMAILADDR
,INACTIVE
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(EMAILADDR,'')='' THEN 'ADMIN@MYCOMPANY.COM' ELSE EMAILADDREND
,CASE WHEN AGE>60 THEN 'SENIOR' ELSE 'EMP' END
```

I understand the Select clause is evaluated after the Group by clause. What I am confused/trying to get my head around is - in what situations do we use the column name vs the contents from the select statement (concat/case in this example) in the group by clause?

Example: In group by above, we could get rid of `FIRSTNAME + ' '+ LASTNAME` and replace it with `FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME`. Also we could replace the `CASE` statements with the `EMAILADDR, AGE`.

**Question:**

1. I am trying to understand in which situations this is OK to do and in which situations is it absolutely necessary that we must place the `CASE` statement (or the concat string operation) from select clause into the Group By clause?
2. In situations where it is OK to use either, what is the best practice to follow? Use the case statement as is from select in the group by? Or only use column names involved in the case statement?

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` clause defines expressions that can be referenced without aggregation in the `SELECT`.  So, this is allowed:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME + ' ' + LASTNAME
. . . 
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
```

because `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME` can be referenced without aggregation functions.  So, any expressions are allowed as well.

On the other hand, this is *not* allowed:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
. . . 
GROUP BY
```

In this case, `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME` are *not* in the `GROUP BY`, so they are not allowed.  This is also allowed:

```
SELECT HONORIFIC + ' ' + FIRSTNAME + ' ' + LASTNAME 
. . . 
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME + ' ' + LASTNAME, HONORIFIC
```

However, this is not allowed:

```
SELECT HONORIFIC + ' ' + FIRSTNAME + ' ' + LASTNAME 
. . . 
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME + ' ' + LASTNAME + HONORIFIC
```